# adding new url patterns to urls.py on the fly in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to add new url patterns to the projects urls.py(not an apps urls) on the fly. I couldn't find anything about this on stackoverflow!

Edit:
I'm writing a simple scaffolding app. For a given model, I create forms, views, templates, and urls.py for an app on the fly. The last thing is to add(attach) urls.py of the app to the urls.py of the project automatically.

Comment: could you expand your question, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Better do it by declaring generic regex, that will match you new url pattern.

Comment: I'm writing a simple scaffolding app. For a given model, I create forms, views, templates, and urls.py for an app on the fly. The last thing is to add(attach) urls.py of the app to the urls.py of the project automatically.

Comment: The solution your are asking for is a very bad idea; it is better to simply create a pattern `/a/<app_name>/<model_name>/add`, `/a/<app_name>/<model_name>/delete`, etc.

Comment: Burhan I dont think you have understood my question!

Comment: @user3474181 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 2):

Django routing does not allow such dynamics, as the routing table is built once in the application startup and never refreshed. Even if it where refreshable then you should communicate the routing table changes across different server processes using database, sockets, Redis pubsub or such mechanism and you would be bending Django framework for something it was not designed to do.

Instead, as the suggestion is, you need one generic regex hook to match the all URLs you want to be "dynamic". Then, inside the view code of this generic URL you can do your own routing based on the full input URL and the available data (E.g. from database). You can even build your own [Django URL resolver](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/django/core/urlresolvers.html) inside the view if you wish to do so, though this might not be a problem-free approach.

Generally, the better approach to solve the situation like this is called traversal. Django does not natively support traversal, [but other Python web frameworks like Pyramid support traversal](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html).

Comment: I'm running the app as a custom django-admin command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/) so the server is not actually running. I think the best option is to try to find the urls.py file and write the new urls to it.!!! something like this open('../../urls.py') as f, f.write(new_urls)

Comment: Python cannot automatically reload this file. You would need to restart the server on every change. I suggest take a different approach as suggested, because rewriting URLs have no point.

Comment: thats what I said, while I'm re-writing the urls the server is not running... so I think it will be fine. the server has to be restarted when the scaffolding process is finished...